# How to handle requireJs timeout error?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm writing a mobile hybrid app using require.js as my loading framework. I have an issue with loading errors. What I'm trying to do is setup a fallback solution when the device is offline and I can't download the google maps API script that I need to display a map on the screen. All that I get is

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true
```

but I'm not able to catch this error and provide an alternative implementation. Here is my gmaps module definition

```
define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'],function(){
  return window.google.maps;
});
```

What can I do?

**EDIT**

I managed to find a possible solution thanks to your help. I've setup require like this

```
require.config({
    paths: {        
        gmaps: ['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', 'lib/dummymaps']
    }
}
```

dummymaps is only a simple module:

```
define({
   dummy: true
});
```

Then in my "parent" module I do:

```
define(["gmaps"],function(gmaps){
    ...
    if(typeof gmaps.dummy != 'undefined' && gmaps.dummy == true){
        // use a local image as map
    } else {
        // initialize google maps canvas
    }
});
```

Do you think that's a good solution?

**EDIT 2:**

Forgive me, it's not working with this code. It's always falling back to the alternative implementation because gmaps needs to use async plugin to be fully loaded and I'm not able to make it work with the plugin.

Comment: Whatever you do, definitely go for a protocol relative url (Starting with //) so you don't run into problems with http and https. Those problems are browser specific, users may see warnings or the JS-Files will not load at all.

Examples: http://cdnjs.com/

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the reason why that kind of urls is used nowadays!

Comment: I am also having this issue, where is the timeout error caught, if ever? I cannot catch it locally or on the the global error handler.

It's google analytics causing me my problem and if that times out I simply want to continue loading the module.

Comment: @MattDerrick I was never able to catch the timeout error and recover from it.  The most I was ever able to do was log the error.  Have a look at the answer I posted to see if this utility library might help you out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26368189/663193

Answer (score 8):

You can catch the error by :

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        alert("error: "+err);
    } 
    else {
        throw err;
    }   
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        // define an alias here, first try remote, if it fails it will try your local file
        'gmaps': ['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', 'your local file.js']
    }
});

define('gmaps', function(gm) {
    // var gm should now be the google maps plugin
    console.log(gm);
});
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution based on this, more or less.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it with this snippet:

```
require(['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'], function() {
    //Success processing
}, function (e) {
    //Error processing
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The RequireJS documentation has [a section on errors](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors) which will cover your particular case.

It details [falling back to a local copy of jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks) should the CDN be unavailable.

Comment: It's not the same. I don't want to replace gmaps implementation. I would like to make one of my modules dependent on gmaps but if gmaps isn't the real one the modules should change its behaviour. Is it possible?

Comment: Theoretically, you could adapt https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks to just reload the module, but IME requireJS does not run the dependent module after retrying the timed-out one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your original problem was never solved exactly how you wanted, and we ran in to the same kind of issue here.  Basically, we wanted a way to recover gracefully when google maps timed out or was unavailable, as there are times our application will run on a user's machine where they do not have internet access.

I was originally using the async! plugin that everyone else uses, but could not come up with a modification that allow for the error handling I needed.

Therefore, I wrote my own utility class that loads google maps asynchronously outside of the requireJS container, and provides error callback handling.  Take a look and see if it solves your issue.  For us, it allows us to render a nice warning view to the user when maps.google.com can't be reached, and the rest of the application still loads normally:

https://github.com/mag382/googleMapsLoaderUtil