# How to catch a load error with RequireJS when Google Maps times out?

Tags: google-maps, requirejs

I'm currently using the Async plugin to load Google Maps in our application using RequireJS (https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins):

```
define("googleMap", ['async!https://maps.googlee.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false']);
```

Then include it wherever I need it:

```
define(['googleMap'], function () { ... });
```

From China for example, Google Maps is forbidden and it will result with a **"Load timeout for modules: async!googleMap"**. This will also break the entire website as the dependency is not available.

How can I catch that error so the app can run? Then wherever I use googleMap I would check that the object 'google' exists before using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle requireJs timeout error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332748/how-to-handle-requirejs-timeout-error)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `ping` the site before you pull your js, just like this answer does:

[Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript/4282218#4282218)